# In Python, is there a way to recover an element of a list that has been deleted with del?

Tags: python

I have started to learn programming in the past weeks, and I'm following the book "Invent your own computer games with python" by Al Sweigart, to create games using the python terminal.

In one of the exercises I have to code a Hangman game, where you guess the letters of a word. To set the difficulty level I have a list with 7 hangman ASCII images (that would give 7 guesses), and a function where the user inputs the difficulty Easy (7 guesses), Medium (5 guesses) or Hard (3 guesses), by deleting the right amount of elements from the list of Hangman images.

```
difficulty = "x"
def difficulty_level():
    while difficulty not in "EMH":
        print("Difficulty level sets the number of guesses available.")
        print('\nE - Easy (7 guesses) \nM - Medium (5 guesses) \nH - Hard (3 guesses)')
        print()
        print("Select the difficulty: ", end="")
        difficulty = input().upper()
        print()
        if difficulty == "E":
            return "E"
        elif difficulty == "M":
            del HANGMAN_PICS[0]
            del HANGMAN_PICS[1]
            return "M"
        elif difficulty == "H":
            del HANGMAN_PICS[0]
            del HANGMAN_PICS[1]
            del HANGMAN_PICS[2]
            del HANGMAN_PICS[3]
            return "H"
        else:
            print("Please choose a difficulty level.")
```

This works well the first time you play, but as you can choose to play again after finishing the round, I want to be able to choose the difficulty again, but the HANGMAN_PICS are already deleted so going from a Medium game to an Easy one is not possible.

How can I recover the deleted HANGMAN_PICS each time the game runs again?

Comment: maybe try passing in a copy of HANGMAN_PICS to your function instead of the original each time you run the function.

Comment: Instead of returning a character you can try to return a slice of the list or a tuple with both. At medium you will then return ("M", HANGMAN_PICS[2:]). It looks like you're using your HANGMAN_PICS as global, so you would still have your original that way and you can then work with the return value of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to recover the deleted elements.

However for your purposes, you may want to pass a copy of the original list to your function so that original can be preserved.

`HANGMAN_PICS.copy()` will do the trick.